# Rename variable inside function in r using normal evaluation

Tags: r, function, evaluation

Say you have the following function that compares two dataframe column types to one another:

```
dataframe_test <- function(df1, df2) {

  varnames <- names(df1)[names(df1) %in% names(df2)]
  out <- data.frame(
             df1 = sapply(df1[,varnames], class),
             df2 = sapply(df2[,varnames], class)
             ) 
  out$Test <- ifelse(out$df1 == out$df2, " - ", "FLAG")

  return(out)

  }
```

Here's the function in use:

```
iris2 <- iris

dataframe_test(iris, iris2)

                 df1     df2 Test
Sepal.Length numeric numeric   - 
Sepal.Width  numeric numeric   - 
Petal.Length numeric numeric   - 
Petal.Width  numeric numeric   - 
Species       factor  factor   -
```

How can I go about renaming the columns of the output of that function (iris, iris2 in my example above) such that they're the same name as the input dataframes? Everything I've tried has produced one error or another. For example,

```
out <- rename_(out, .dots = setNames(list(df1), new))
colnames(out) <- c(glue::glue("{df1}"), glue::glue("{df2}"), "Flag")
```

But nothing has worked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `deparse()` and `substitute()` to turn symbol to strings:

```r
dataframe_test <- function(df1, df2) {

  varnames <- names(df1)[names(df1) %in% names(df2)]
  out <- data.frame(
    df1 = sapply(df1[,varnames], class),
    df2 = sapply(df2[,varnames], class)
  ) 
  out$Test <- ifelse(out$df1 == out$df2, " - ", "FLAG")
  names(out) <- c(deparse(substitute(df1)), deparse(substitute(df2)), "Test")

  return(out)

}

iris2 <- iris

dataframe_test(iris, iris2)
#>                 iris   iris2 Test
#> Sepal.Length numeric numeric   - 
#> Sepal.Width  numeric numeric   - 
#> Petal.Length numeric numeric   - 
#> Petal.Width  numeric numeric   - 
#> Species       factor  factor   -
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

We can use `deparse` and `substitute` to get the dataframe name and refer column name by position in `ifelse`.

```
dataframe_test <- function(df1, df2) {

   data1 <- deparse(substitute(df1))
   data2 <- deparse(substitute(df2))
   varnames <- names(df1)[names(df1) %in% names(df2)]
   out <- setNames(data.frame(sapply(df1[,varnames], class),
                sapply(df2[,varnames], class)), c(data1, data2))
   out$Test <- ifelse(out[[1]] == out[[2]], " - ", "FLAG")
   return(out)
}

dataframe_test(iris, iris2)

#                iris   iris2 Test
#Sepal.Length numeric numeric   - 
#Sepal.Width  numeric numeric   - 
#Petal.Length numeric numeric   - 
#Petal.Width  numeric numeric   - 
#Species       factor  factor   -
```